# Rename a column where both the old column name and the new column name are shiny inputs?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, rlang

Pretty much what the title says. How do I rename a column of a reactive data frame when the column to be renamed and the new name are both selected by the user via selectInput?

Here is the code that is broken:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  sidebarPanel(
    #sliders
    uiOutput("old_column"),
    uiOutput("new_column")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    #display df
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  #init reactives
  cars <- reactiveVal(as.data.frame(mpg))

  #display data
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(cars(),
              selection = 'single',
              options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                             scrollX = TRUE,
                             searching = FALSE,
                             lengthChange = FALSE))
  })

  ##creating dropdowns
  observe({
    output$old_column <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput("old_column",
                     "Which column do you want to rename?",
                     c(names(cars())), selected = NULL)
    })
  })

  observe({
    output$new_column <- renderUI({
      names <- c("red", "blue", "green", "orange")
      selectizeInput("new_column",
                     "What would you like to name it?",
                     names, selected = NULL)
    })
  })

 #rename column
  observe({
    req(input$new_column)
    req(input$old_column)
    #this is the bad line!!!
    cars(cars() %>%
        dplyr::rename(input$new_column = input$old_column))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried a bunch of rlang things like `!!as.name(input$new_column) := input$old_column` but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo that may be helpful.

- First, I renamed `cars` to `my_cars` since `cars` was a dataset (also using `mtcars` instead of `mpg` for convenience)
- I removed the `observe` for the outputs as not needed
- Included `observeEvent` such that the column names will change when a new column name is selected (a button or other ui strategy may work as well)
- I use `!!` (bang-bang operator) for programmatic access to the variable names when renaming, which requires `:=` for assignment

Also, would be aware that duplicate column name problems may occur. In addition, since the `selectizeInput`s are generated in `server`, the default column name (in this case first column name) will be changed (`observeEvent` triggered upon start).

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  sidebarPanel(
    #sliders
    uiOutput("old_column"),
    uiOutput("new_column")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    #display df
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #init reactives
  my_cars <- reactiveVal(mtcars)
  
  #display data
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(my_cars(),
              selection = 'single',
              options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                             scrollX = TRUE,
                             searching = FALSE,
                             lengthChange = FALSE))
  })
  
  ##creating dropdowns
  output$old_column <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("old_column",
                   "Which column do you want to rename?",
                   names(my_cars()), 
                   selected = NULL)
  })
  
  output$new_column <- renderUI({
    names <- c("red", "blue", "green", "orange")
    selectizeInput("new_column",
                   "What would you like to name it?",
                   names, 
                   selected = NULL)
  })
  
  #rename column
  observeEvent(input$new_column, {
    
    req(input$new_column)
    req(input$old_column)
    
    my_cars(
      my_cars() %>%
        rename(!!input$new_column := !!input$old_column)
    )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr::rename_with()`.

Here is a small reprex:

```r
old <- 'mpg'
new <- 'gpm'

colnames(mtcars)
#>  [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
#> [11] "carb"

mtcars |> 
  dplyr::rename_with(
    .fn = ~ new, 
    .cols = dplyr::all_of(old)
  ) |> 
  colnames()
#>  [1] "gpm"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
#> [11] "carb"
```

So in your case you can do this:

```r
# ...

  # rename column
  observe({
    req(input$new_column)
    req(input$old_column)
    
    x <- cars() %>%
      dplyr::rename_with(
        .fn = ~ input$new_column,
        .cols = dplyr::all_of(input$old_column)
      )
    # then do whatever you wish with `x`
    # for example:
    print(head(x))
  })

# ...
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error when I put this code in the shiny app. It says `Warning: Error in dplyr::rename_with: Problem while evaluating `dplyr::all_of(input$old_column)`.
Caused by error in `dplyr::all_of()`:
! Can't subset elements that don't exist.
✖ Element `manufacturer` doesn't exist.`